# Sitecore Search Api - How to get formatted Url

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

How can I get the formatted url from Sitecore Lucene search? I created a custom index and updated it with under root as /sitecore/content/websitename/home.

When the search results are retrieved the URL is appended with https://hostname/websitename/home/sample.aspx. I would like the url to be https://hostname/sample.aspx. Is there any setting in index config that needs to be updated?

In sites.config I already have  rootPath="/sitecore/content/websitename"   startItem="/home"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the url in two ways:

1. For each result from your index, fetch the item and get the url with the `LinkManager` as you normally would for any item. This does mean that you need to fetch the items what will be a performance hit.
2. Create a computed field in your index to include the url. In your computed field, make sure the correct link is being generated. If not, you might need to check your url options and the maybe the `Rendering.SiteResolving` setting (true). Verify the results with a debugger (or with Luke to test the index). Remember that if you include the url in the index, you will need to update additional items when an item is renamed (or even the display name changed when that is used in the url). All children of that changed item had their urls changed as well at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and I went with the second option. However I still had to get the context site. Here is what I have implemented(In case if any one needs):                                                                                                    Item item = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

            if (item != null)
            {
                var options = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
                options.Site = SiteContext.GetSite("website");
                
                return "https" + LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options);
            }

Comment: Don't hardcode with url schema . Use a method to get current schema: public static string GetScheme()
{
    HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
    if (current != null)
        return current.Request.Url.Scheme;
    return string.Empty;
}